# RLC circuit problem

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical, circuits

[image]

After the switch is open for a long time, it is closed at t = 0.
How can I find iL(t) and Vc(t) for t>=0?
I tried step response for RLC circuit but I could not apply.

Comment: suggest migrating to EE forum....

Comment: Is this a HW problem? Can you share what you tried?